# Catan Universe with 2 human and 1 computer player

Tags: catan

I have played a lot of Catan on the original board game but there is Catan Classic or Catan Universe in the App Store.

Can I play Catan online with a friend but also against the computer so we have minimum 3 player which makes it more challenging than a 2 player version?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't provide you with assistance on how to play a game on an online site and what that site will allow you to play with for computer and human opponents. You will need to visit the site in question itself to find that answer.

Comment: Instead of closing the question, why not to wait for someone that played at that site? should be an easy question.

Comment: Please reopen. Closing this because it require knowledge of the site is like closing a question because it requires knowledge of the rules. Questions about the electronic versions of board games are on topic.

Comment: @ikegami Are we expected to be able to provide support for every gaming site and game that is based on a board game?

Comment: @ikegami This is looking for not only a recommendation but a recommendation for a computer version of a game, which takes this FAR out of scope for BGSE. They are looking for a platform that allows both human and computer players - this is not our scope.

Comment: @Andrew, No, they are asking if two specific games are able to do something. I have no idea why you think that's asking for a recommendation. The fact that they are really asking two questions is a problem, though.

Comment: @Joe W, The question is whether we allow questions about those, and the answer at this time is yes. Whether you answer ("provide support") or not is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can play with both players and AIs in *Catan Universe*, at least on the PC version.

1. Choose the game to play (*The Game*, *Seafarers*, *Cities & Knights*, etc) by click the appropriate button at the bottom of the screen.
2. Choose "Custom Game"
3. To add a player,

   1. Click "+" next to "Add player".
   2. Choose "Friendlist".
   3. Enter the name of a friend.
4. To add an AI,

   1. Click "+" next to "Add player".
   2. Choose "Computer (AI)".
   3. Select an AI name.
5. Repeat the last two steps as desired.

I can't answer for *Catan Classic*.

Comment: Morgan here. Thank you for that detailed answer “ikegami”, that answers my question completely!

Comment: @Morgan, Thanks, but the appropriate course of action is to click the checkmark next to the answer :)